# Show that $\liminf(\sqrt{x_n})=\sqrt{\liminf x_n}$

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers such that $x_n \ge0$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$. Show that $\liminf(\sqrt{x_n})=\sqrt{\liminf x_n}$.

I assume we need to consider the subsequence of ($\sqrt{x_n}$), but I'm really confused with the  notion on "boundedness". Can I assume the question implies an upper bound on $(x_n)$?

Even then wouldn't the equation be implied? Given how roots generally affect limits.

Comment: Yes, it implies. Bounded sequence means that there exists an $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n\leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Such problems are usually solved by expansion of the definitions. (BTW, use "\inf" instead of "inf" to make the formulas looking better)

Comment: There's pretty much nothing to do once you use the following property: $\lim \inf x_n$ is the smallest limit a convergent subsequence of $x_n$ can have.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM The problem i'm having is actually explicitly showing it. I thought of taking one such limit e.g. $u \in S(x_n)$ and showing that if $u$ is the smallest limit in $S(x_n)$ then $\sqrt{u}$ is the smallest limit in $S(\sqrt{x_n})$. But this turns into and if and only if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be using the following property: 
Given a sequence $x_n$, $\lim \inf x_n$ is the smallest limit a convergent subsequence of $x_n$ can have.

Let $x_{n_k}$ be a subsequence of $x_n$ that converges to $\lim \inf x_n$.

Then $\sqrt{x_{n_k}}$ converges to $\sqrt{\lim \inf x_n}$. But $\sqrt{x_{n_k}}$ is a subsequence of $\sqrt{x_{n}}$. Hence $\lim \inf \sqrt{x_{n}}\leq \sqrt{\lim \inf x_n}$.

The reverse inequality can be proved in a similar fashion.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please include the details for the reverse inequality as well? I think we could get the reverse inequality for $\lim \sup$, but I don't see how to get it for $\lim \inf$

Comment: @Blue Let $n_k$ be indexes such that $\sqrt{x_{n_k}}$ converges to  $\lim \inf \sqrt{x_{n}}$. Since $x_{n_k} = \sqrt{x_{n_k}} ^2$ is a subsequence of $x_n$ that goes to $(\lim \inf \sqrt{x_{n}})^2$ , we have $\liminf x_n \leq (\lim \inf \sqrt{x_{n}})^2$, hence $$\sqrt{\liminf x_n} \leq \lim \inf \sqrt{x_{n}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!